# What happens to a Windows Service on a Surface Pro during shutdown?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-services

I've got a .NET 4.5 Windows service running on a Surface Pro with Windows 8. It's set to "Automatic" startup type.

I override and log (to a file, via log4net) all of the following methods in ServiceBase:

- OnStart
- OnStop
- OnPause
- OnContinue
- OnPowerEvent
- OnShutdown

However, when I shut down and restart the Surface Pro (through any number of methods: Alt+F4 on the desktop -> "Shut down", Sign Out -> Shut Down from start screen, etc.) I don't see my service logging from any of the events above, as if it had just kept on running. (This is a problem for my service -- the resources it's holding onto need to be stopped and restarted properly, or else they'll be in a bad state after the "shutdown".)

I know from a bit of research that the Surface Pro isn't really and truly powering off when I shut it down, but this still strikes me as very unusual; I'd expect to get ONE of these events. What might I be doing wrong here?